# Duplicate classes in Magento

Tags: magento

I have the latest magento instance running and I wonder why there are duplicate classes in includes folder.

For instance, Varien_Data_Collection is defined in includes/src/Varien/Data/Collection.php and in includes/src/Varien_Data_Collection.php and in src/__default.php. How could that happen?

Also, the same applies to other classes in includes package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out it by myself. The error that was happening due to duplicate classes has gone away when compilation was switched off in Admin.